# WCF service receiving NULL values

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a new web service I'm trying to implement... when I run it in the debugger the function being called in the service stops at the breakpoint I set but I notice that the value is null... I've burnt myself the last day trying to figure this out.

I apologize if I seem scatterbrained or not giving enough info...I appreciate any help

I have also tried it from Fiddler as well; it stops at the breakpoint like above.

I'm thinking my json might be screwy?

The call from the client:

```
 var url = "http://localhost:35798/Service.svc/Test;
 var json = '{"name": "test"}';
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                alert("Passed" + data.CheckFileResult);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```

The service:

```
[OperationContract] 
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
public string Test(string name)
 {
    return "hi";
 }
```

Service Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Site.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="Site.ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

  <services>
    <service name="Site.Service">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Site.ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Site.Service" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using the service reference to connect to the methods and then I watched the request in fiddler and realized that the json was indeed malformed...There was an extra space

```
'{ "name":"test"}'
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

What about syntax of this line:

```
var json = '{"name": "test"}'
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
var json = '{name: "test"}';
```

Edit: Your first two lines seems to be a bit off imo. Try:

```
var url = "http://localhost:35798/Service.svc/Test";
var json = "{name: 'test'}";
```

Comment: Sorry I was copy/pasting fast; I tried to change the json, but it still didn't work. Also I tried your json example at jsonlint.com and it didn't like it. Thanks, however!